# How to display dynamic PHP javascript calendar

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Below is the javascript code am fetching the dates from the database table booking,apparently the calendar is displaying the patient id and not the name and time:The database is mysqli how do i make it display the row time and name and also make it a link

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
    // CALENDAR
        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            editable: true,
            height: 550,
            events: [

                <?php 
                $sql2= mysqli_query($db_conn,"SELECT autoid,day,month,year,time,patientid as time FROM booking");

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2))
                {
                $autoid = $row['autoid'];
                $day = $row['day'];
                $month = $row['month'];
                $year = $row['year'];
                $time = $row['time'];
                $patientid = $row['patientid'];

                $sql5="SELECT * FROM patients WHERE autoid='$patientid'";
                $result5=mysqli_query($db_conn,  $sql5);
                $row5 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result5) ;
                $fname= $row5["fname"] ;
                $lname= $row5["lname"] ;    
               ?>
       { title: '<?php echo $lname;?>-<?php echo $time;?>', start: '<?php echo $year;?>, <?php echo $month;?>, <?php echo $day;?>', end: '<?php echo $year;?>, <?php echo $month;?>, <?php echo $day;?>', url: '#' }, 

      <?php
      }

      ?>
                {
                    title: 'Click for ThemeForest',
                    start: new Date(2030, m, 28),
                    end: new Date(2030, m, 29),
                    url: '#'
                }
            ]
        });
     });

    });
        </script>
```

Comment: What do you mean? I don't understand your question. I see you echo the time etc. So maybe your query is wrong?

Comment: I have echoed the time anf fname which is first name but the result is that it is echoing the patientid instead of the time and name

Comment: There is one way. Instead of displaying your dynamic calendar in javascript, It is possible to display only dates coming from DB in jQuery Datepicker.

Comment: how can i display only dates

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your query: ... time, patientid as time ...
patientid is overriding time

Comment: i want the query to display time and the first name(fname)

Comment: Also you can get rid of your second query using a join. Will be much faster as you'll only hit the db once

Comment: so how should i type my query so that the patientid does not overwrite the time

Comment: just remove the "as time" after patientid